# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;

Tags: json, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, gson

When I try to create a RemoteWebDriver in 3.11, I see this error below.
This worked fine up through 3.10. I've reverted to 3.10 for now.

I tried adding in the gson jar from google, but I still see same error.
Anyone else see this? I'm running one selenium server as hub, and then running
a node against it with webdriver for ff or chrome, same issue.

```
com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
at org.openqa.selenium.json.Json.(Json.java:47)
at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.constructMessage(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:37)
at org.openqa.selenium.logging.profiler.HttpProfilerLogEntry.(HttpProfilerLogEntry.java:29)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:135)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:132)
at oracle.ojet.automation.test.selenium.WebDriverManager._buildRemoteWebDriver(WebDriverManager.java:573)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder.setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
```

...implies that the **JVM** was unable to find the method `setLenient()Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder`.

---

### Reason

*Release Notes* of **Selenium v3.10.0** clearly mentions:

> - Migrate Selenium Grid to reduce exporting GSON and Apache HttpClient as much to public APIs.

Further, *Release Notes* of **Selenium v3.12.0** clearly mentions:

> - Remove GSON from how we coerce JSON to Java types.
> - Clean up the internals of Selenium's JSON handling, including deprecating places where GSON leaks from our APIs.

Finally, *Release Notes* of **Selenium v3.13.0** clearly mentions:

> - Introduced our own JSON parser and outputter, allowing GSON to be removed from our dependencies.

### Solution

To get rid of the *warning* and errors upgrade to **Selenium v3.14.0**, where *Release Notes* clearly mentions:

> - Completely removed the GSON dependency. We now use reflection to try and find the class.

Comment: @YogeshRathi **Upvote** the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.